# vertical align to the bottom of chat page and page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am creating a chat application with AJAX and PHP. I have successfully been able to get the chats aligned at the bottom of the div in which chats appear. When new messages are loaded, the messages are succcessfully added to the bottom of the div and using JS I am getting the scroll bar to the bottom to show new message. Just like below:

```
if(document.getElementById("oldmessages").scrollTopMax)
               {
                   if(document.getElementById("oldmessages").scrollTopMax > document.getElementById("oldmessages").clientHeight)
                   {
                   document.getElementById("oldmessages").scrollTop = document.getElementById("oldmessages").scrollTopMax;
                   }
               }
```

The problem, is that every time new chat is loaded by ajax request which constantly polls the server, at that time this code is fired and every time the scroll bar comes to bottom. Even if the user might be checking messages above the last messages, it still behaves like this , because I am not sure how to rectify this. Is there a way to help solve this and not let the scroll bar scroll to bottom when user is checking messages above the last message?

Please contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.scrollTop` for get the `position` of `scroll` at the time of `ajax` is fire.
if `position` of `scroll bar` is not at the `bottom` than set the position at `old position`. At first time you can set the `position` of `scroll` at the `bottom`.